# Handling back button in case of multiple setContentView's

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity, say FirstActivity, and multiple views that are utilized by it. 
Views are switched by clicking buttons on screen.
Currently, I handle back button (to return to previous view) this way:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode,KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (current == ViewNum.VIEW_DEFAULT) {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
            }
            else {
                setContentView(R.layout.firstactivitynew);
                configureUI();
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
        }
    }
}
```

This, obviously, works only if I have one nested contentView, and this is a case.
However, I have a feel that there is something terribly wrong with this way of handling this. Is there any 'standard' way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make use of `Tabs` and `Fragments`, and should forget about the possibility of changing the activity view with `setContentView` multiple times.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

But technically, you can also keep track of your "application state" and redefine the `onBackPressed()` method to take your view back to the previous view at a given state.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make use of the [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method:

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
>   but you can override this to do whatever you want.